# EPS light illuminates on 2012 Accent

Tags: hyundai, power-steering, accent

The EPS light came on last Saturday and the power steering stopped working, after leaving it for a short time re started the car and light was off and steering working normally.  About half hour later the same thing happened, again after re start all OK. Did not use the car for the next day and then the same thing happened again.  Has been working fine since then and have booked it in at local dealer for Monday, they informed me that it will cost $250 diagnostic check. 
I am a bit concerned that they may say that they cant diagnose the problem and send me away to possibly have the same thing happen again with another $250.
The book says take it straight to your dealer, but I still have to wait a week.

Hank

Comment: You need to have the codes read to start. Get another estimate for diag somewhere else. If the problem is repeatable than there shouldn’t be any problems at the very least a code will be stored.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading in my 2012 Honda Civic owners manual about the electric assist steering system. It mentioned that if you hold the steering wheel too long at the extreme right or left position it will overheat the system and trigger the EPS light. When it cools down it returns to normal function and the light goes out. Probably a similar triggered this event.

I also vaguely remember reading something online regarding the ABS wheel speed sensors affecting the Electronic Stability  Control that also triggered that light.

Comment: The car was being driven along a outer suburban road, with curves and straight sections so I dont think aggressive turning could be the cause.

Comment: It could also be a sensor issue as well. Without a diagnostic code we are searching blindly for the problem,